# Do I need to claim my baggage while connecting in Chicago?

Tags: transit, luggage, ord, air-canada, asiana-airlines

I am going to Korea with Asiana Airlines. My initiary is from Montreal, Canada (Air Canada) --> Chicago -> Incheon, KOR (Asiana).

I will need to take an ATS to transfer terminals while connecting in Chicago; do I need to claim my baggage or they will automatically send it to the airline (Asiana?)

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Is your trip booked as a single ticket, or did you buy your Air Canada and Asiana tickets separately?

Comment: Yes it's was booked as a single ticket , i wasn't sure since it's not the same airline. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this itineray was purchased as one ticket, you will clear US customs at the US pre-clearance facility in Montréal and your bag will be forwarded to your Asiana flight for you.

You do not need to collect it in Chicago. Your bag will be sent to Incheon.

Answer (score 0):

If tickets bought together as 1 trip. Baggage should go through to final stop. If separate tickets then you need pick up at each stop. Does the ticket say with other airlines? then pick up in Korea. Last stop.